# Не удаляет класc при клике по кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не удаляет и не добавляет класс?

```js
var tmp = 0;
$('.deslidt').on("click", ".btn-hide", function() {
  tmp = tmp + 1;
  if (tmp == 1) {
    $(this).html("Скрыть");
    $(".video-des .deslidt ul li #no_add").removeClass("hidden");

  }
  if (tmp == 2) {
    tmp = 0;
    $(this).html("Показать");
    $(".video-des .deslidt ul li #no_add").toggleClass("hidden");

  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deslidt">
  <ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li id="no_add" class="hidden">
    </li>
    <li id="no_add" class="hidden">
    </li>
    <button class="btn-hide">Показать</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все это делается проще, но вот Ваш код с исправлениями:

```js
var tmp = 0;
$('.deslidt').on("click", ".btn-hide", function() {
  tmp = tmp + 1;
  if (tmp == 1) {
    $(this).html("Скрыть");
    $(".deslidt ul li.no_add").removeClass("hidden");
  }
  if (tmp == 2) {
    tmp = 0;
    $(this).html("Показать");
    $(".deslidt ul li.no_add").toggleClass("hidden");
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deslidt">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 0</li>
    <li class="no_add hidden">Item 1</li>
    <li class="no_add hidden">Item 2</li>
    <button class="btn-hide">Показать</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```